# ¿Cómo se puede añadir una fila a un datatable en C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Esta pregunta está relacionada con la anterior (relacionada con IsBindingSuspended). Necesito añadir una fila a a una tabla de mi datasource. El código es el siguiente:

```
private void CrearDataSetAux(ref DataSet dataSetAux)
        {
            String sqlInsertPrueba = "INSERT INTO dat_fonts (IdFont, Descripcion, Operacion) VALUES(1, ' ', 'A');";
            sqlInsertPrueba = AccesoDatosGenerico.AdaptarSentenciaProveedor(sqlInsertPrueba);
            AccesoDatosGenerico.EjecutaNonQuery(AccesoDatosGenerico.Connection, sqlInsertPrueba);
            //Tras el insert, hacemos el select para el dataset
           String sqlDatasetInicio = "SELECT * FROM dat_fonts";

            dataSetAux.Tables[0].Rows.Add(AccesoDatosGenerico.EjecutaQuery(AccesoDatosGenerico.Connection, sqlDatasetInicio).Tables[0]);
           
        }
```

El problema es al añadir la columna me aparece la siguiente excepción:

**

> System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
> 'System.Data.DataTable' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'.No se puede
> almacenar  en la columna IdFont. El tipo esperado es Int32.'

**
¿Existe alguna forma de solucionarlo? Las insert y select funcionan correctamente. Todo va bien hasta ese punto. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

## Agregar datos a una tabla de datos

Después de crear una DataTable y definir su estructura usando columnas y restricciones, puede agregar nuevas filas de datos a la tabla. Para agregar una nueva fila, declare una nueva variable como tipo DataRow . Se devuelve un nuevo objeto DataRow cuando llama al método NewRow. El DataTable continuación, crea el DataRow objeto basado en la estructura de la mesa, tal como se define por el DataColumnCollection.

El siguiente ejemplo demuestra cómo crear una nueva fila llamando al método NewRow .

```
DataRow workRow = workTable.NewRow();
```

Luego puede manipular la fila recién agregada usando un índice o el nombre de la columna, como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
workRow["CustLName"] = "Smith";  
workRow[1] = "Smith";
```

Una vez que se insertan los datos en la nueva fila, el método Add se usa para agregar la fila a DataRowCollection , que se muestra en el siguiente código.

```
workTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
```

También puede llamar al método Add para agregar una nueva fila pasando una matriz de valores, escritos como Object , como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
workTable.Rows.Add(new Object[] {1, "Smith"});
```

Pasar una matriz de valores, escrita como Objeto, al método Agregar crea una nueva fila dentro de la tabla y establece sus valores de columna en los valores de la matriz de objetos. Tenga en cuenta que los valores de la matriz se hacen coincidir secuencialmente con las columnas, según el orden en que aparecen en la tabla.

El siguiente ejemplo agrega 10 filas a la tabla Clientes recién creada .

```
DataRow workRow;  
  
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{  
  workRow = workTable.NewRow();  
  workRow[0] = i;  
  workRow[1] = "CustName" + i.ToString();  
  workTable.Rows.Add(workRow);  
}
```